# C# List Find 'Object'

Tags: c#, list, find

Probably a simple question but it's late at night, hopefully someone can slap me over the back of my head

Main class holds several lists of classes

Script finds what was clicked on, stores it as an 'object' type

Script does a GetType comparison, and runs code specific to class

How can I do a `List.Find(the selected object)`

Code as by request;

```
object selectedObject; // Set by mousehandler (this works)
List<MyClass> mcList = new List<MyClass>; // Populated (this works)
if (selectedItem.GetType() == typeof(MyClass)) { CallThisMethod(); }; // (this works)
private void method() 
{
   // MyClass mc = mcList.Find( selectedObject );
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackoverFlow. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learn about [how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: No one is able to help you without looking at your code. What did you try and what error did you get?

Comment: code is irrelevant, I need to know what List.Find variables to use to compare the object to list item

Comment: @DrizzleXT at list post the code where `list` is being generated and the object which you want to find in list

Comment: Added as per request, but it's really irrelevant to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you cast it?

```
if (selectedItem is MyClass selectedItemMyClassCasted) 
{ 
   CallThisMethod(selectedItemMyClassCasted); 
}; // (this works)

private void CallThisMethod(MyClass mc) 
{
  //handle mc
}
```

You can also use latest switch pattern matching:

```
switch(selectedItem)
{
   case MyClass myClassItem:
        CallThisMethod(myClassItem);
        break;
   case Class2 class2Item:
        Method2(class2Item);
        break;
   ...
   default:
        throw new ArgumentException(nameof(selectedItem));
}
```

How to use Find method:

```
List<object> lll = new List<object>();
object selectedElement;
...
lll.Find((x) => x.Equals(selectedElement));
```

But I would use FirstOrDefault, since Find can throw Argument exception and it does not make much sense to call it:

```
var result =  lll.FirstOrDefault((x) => x.Equals(selectedElement));
if (result != null)
{
   //do the stuff
}
```

Comment: .Equals, that's what I was looking for, thank you very much!
Will look into this firstordefault alternative, cheers for education <3

Comment: @DrizzleXTSee the topmost example